# jquery anchor on click, convert as form submit not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm converting the `<a>` on click as form submit using jQuery. It is not working in Firefox and working fine in Chrome. Could you please suggest what I missed?

```
$('a.post').each(function(i){
    $(this).off().on('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formelem = '';
        formelem+= '<form name="menu" action="'+$(this).attr('href')+'" method="POST">';
        formelem+= '<input type="hidden" value="testvalue" name="dp">';
        formelem+= '</form>';
        $('body').append(formelem);
        $('form[name="menu"]').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, the form's name is `sideMenu`, not `menu` ... used in `$('form[name="menu"]').submit();` ... and can't understand how that can work in Chrome, but it appears almost anything works in Chrome nowdays

Comment: So was that a typo? ... if so, then simply close this as such, or delete it

Comment: Yes. Its Typo. I'll change it.